# Does Hindu astrology allow for such predictions?

Tags: astrology

How do Hindu astrologers come up with such predictions?

Is there any DOB equivalent for countries?

https://theprint.in/india/twitter-reacts-to-indian-astrologer-who-said-there-will-be-no-war-between-russia-ukraine/846442/

[image]

Comment: This branch of astrology is called Medini Shastra (or Mundane Astrology). Many tools are used. One of the tools is the horoscope of the country. This horoscope is based on the foundation day of the country. For example, in the case of India, it is 15th august 1947. Delhi. Time is midnight, I guess. Like this.

Comment: Which texts elucidate on 'Medini-Shastra'? Can you please tell @AmritenduMukhopadhyay ?

Comment: @Vivikta I do not know the name of any classics in Medini Shastra. However, most likely you will get the name of classics in this field from any modern book. Few modern books are as follows. Practical Mundane Astrology by J C Luthra, Astrology in forecasting weather and earthquake by B V Raman, Mundane Astrology by Manik Chand Jain, Mundane astrology by M N Kedar. These guys are well known in the modern astrology circle. A western classic in Mundane Astrology is Raphael's Mundane Astrology.